# CentOS 6.9 systemctl not found

Tags: services, systemctl, centos-6.6

To list all running or stopped or failed services, systemctl (soon to become systemd in CentOS 7) is just so nice. I just type systemtcl with nothing after it.

service --status-all
gives much fewer informations
But what can be done when servicectl is not found (on the pc or by yum)?

Answer (score 0):

Systemctl was introduced with CentOS 7. I googled the term "CentOS 6.9 systemctl not found" that you put in your title and found the information within 20 seconds.